# Android Database fetching database value

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have one table in that table there is one column and i have set that column value default to 0; but whenever i am accessing that value it cant access. following code that i have tried.

```
 public void getmaxoid() {
        SQLiteDatabase database = dataforcategorylistview.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {"order_id"};
        Cursor cursors = database.rawQuery("Select max(order_id) from sales_item", null);
        if (cursors.moveToNext()) {
            convertedorderid = cursors.getInt(cursors.getColumnIndexOrThrow("order_id"));

            if (convertedorderid==0) {
                int oid = 0;
                //int oid = Integer.parseInt(OrderIdFromService);
                serverorderid = String.valueOf(convertedorderid++);
                orderidset.setText(serverorderid);
            } else {

                serverorderid = String.valueOf(convertedorderid++);
                orderidset.setText(serverorderid);
            }
            cursors.close();
        }

    } And this is my table: 
String salesitem = "CREATE TABLE `sales_item` (`sales_id` integer NOT NULL,`order_id` numeric DEFAULT 0,`menu_id`   nvarchar(500) NOT NULL,`qty`    integer NOT NULL,`rate` numeric NOT NULL,`total_amount` numeric NOT NULL,`w_id` numeric NOT NULL,`kot_id`   integer NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(`sales_id`))";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to

```
Cursor cursors = database.rawQuery("Select max(order_id) as max_order_id from sales_item", null);
```

and

```
convertedorderid = cursors.getInt(cursors.getColumnIndexOrThrow("max_order_id"));
```

Comment: Thanks for giving solution

Answer (score 0):

The column name in the cursor is something like `max(order_id)`. If you have only a single column, you could just hardcode the column index:

```java
convertedorderid = cursors.getInt(0);
```

Anyway, it would be easier to use a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) to read the single result value of a query:

```java
long max_id = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(database,
        "Select max(order_id) from sales_item", null);
```